# Can a cracked toilet be permanently repaired?

Tags: repair, toilet

So I broke the entire corner (top to bottom) off of the tank on my toilet.  The toilet was inherited by me in house, which was a foreclosure.  It is a one-piece that is valued at $1450.      I was able to purchase the exact same toilet in the two-piece version for $300.  Would I be able to repair the broken toilet to use in another bathroom?

I am wondering if some sort of marine or aquarium glue would work to waterproof, then maybe strip the glaze off and sand the patch smooth, then buy a kit to re-glaze?  Is this possible?

Comment: A picture might be helpful.

Comment: Oh the entire corner of the tank part is gone.  Not a chip.  From top to bottom, about 4 inches into each the left and front side.  The entire corner.  It can't hold an inch of water.  Bone headed mistake on my part to break it.

Comment: "Gone" as in "not available anymore"?  What is there to be glued then?

Comment: I have the piece, but it is in entire corner.  I could glue it back on but I would have to fill it in with something at the crack.  Could I strip the glaze, repair it, then take it to a kiln and reglaze it?

Comment: Sadly there is no way to reglaze porcelain with a kiln or attach two pieces together after the porcelain has been fired once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably not worth the risk to fix it.  If you do manage to find an adhesive there is a risk of the repair cracking and leaking causing significant damage.

Comment: +1 If it were the last toilet on earth and the preservation of our cultural icon were at stake, by all means go for it! Otherwise bite the bullet and trash it.

Comment: yeah, just too much trouble. That's crappy.  ;)